# Is it a good idea to add locale-specific tests in the PostgreSQL regression suite?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, internationalization, locale

I am working on a feature related to locales, For testing this, I need to run a few SQL queries by using different locale settings. For Example.

```
SET lc_messages to 'en_US.UTF-8';
-- some sql queries;
SET lc_messages to 'fr_FR.UTF-8';
-- some sql queries;
```

On my Linux machine, it is working but we can't always expect this set or any(except C or POSIX)  locales will be available on other platforms. Is there a way around this problem?

Comment: Is this feature intended for inclusion in core PostgreSQL? Did you research how the core regression tests do it?

Comment: No, this is not intended for inclusion in core PostgreSQL. I searched in the core regression tests, I found one test src/test/regress/sql/collate.sql, In this test, only "C" or "POSIX" locales are used because of the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices:

1. Skip the test if the locale doesn't exist:

   For that, you'd start the test with something like

   ```
   SELECT (SELECT count(*) FROM pg_collation
           WHERE collname = 'fr_FR.UTF-8') = 0
          AS skip_test \gset
   \if :skip_test
   \quit
   ```

   Then provide an alternative “expected result file” for that case.
2. Error out if the locale doesn't exist.  After all, then the test cannot be done properly.

   That may be a good solution if you target only Linux systems.

If you target Windows too, you should try with their locale names as well before failing.